Selenium runs faster when executed via command compared to when running through Windows services
You're using Selenium IEDriverServer to run tests in IEMode of Edge, and i have noticed that running via command is four times faster than running via Windows Services. You've checked the priority using Task Manager and found no difference in priority. Have you encountered this situation before? You want to make running via Windows Services as fast as running via command.
I also tried running it with the highest priority via Task Scheduler, however, the speed still remains slow like with Windows Services.
